# Alternative to abusing div to modularize html code

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm looking to break up html into modules. I wish something like

```
<div src="panel.html" onload="enable('guest-only-buttons');" />
```

were possible.
I am simulating this using an XMLHttpRequest, but it sure feels like a mess of div hacks like back in the days of table based layouts.
Particularly would like modules to be part of a code DOM, so they can be modified, but for the actual DOM to be seamless. Is there something like this available?
I have Firefox android on a tablet only. WebComponents and Shadow DOM are toggled on in about:config.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a framework like Angular.

Comment: To construct an html using modules or components or whatever, there are lots of options depending which technology you are using. In server side rendering you have: laravel, phoenix, rails (among many others) which support "partials". In client side rendering you have React, Vue, Angular, etc.

Comment: This is client only. Vue looks nice, Angular also. I have to check out React. I'm interested in a more tag oriented solution, but eventually json also.

Comment: You can also use vanilla web compontents : native Custom Elements and Shadow Dom, plus HTML Imports polyfill

Comment: How do I load the imports polyfill directly in browser without installing on the server? Via unpkg?

Comment: @zerodrama if you want to use XMLHttpRequest it any JS library of framework which relies on this primitive, you need at least a local HTTP server (e. g. node.js with express.js). If you don't want it you'll have to load modules as Javascript files.